# Sublime Text 2 in OSX: all fonts are bold regardless of theme or font

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I have a weird problem on mac (OSX 10.7): any theme or font I choose - all fonts appear in bold.
I sync all settings with Dropbox and on Windows 7 and Ubuntu the fonts are normal.

Don't know if it's an OSX problem or sublime, but did anyone run into this issue?

Comment: You might be better asking on apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Tried Preferences/Font/Smaller?

Comment: Looks normal on my system (10.8.2).

Comment: @Chris Yes, tried font sizing and different fonts, ALL bold

Comment: When you say "theme" do you mean colorscheme? Because ST Themes affect the UI elements while colorschemes affect font colors and styling.

Comment: @BoundinCode colorscheme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what you're talking about.
Try to add this line in your settings :

```
"font_options": [ "gray_antialias" ]
```

Your code will look sharper (it depends on the font you're using).

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to add two options to get the fonts to look right

```
"font_options":
[
    "no_bold",
    "gray_antialias"
]
```